# Serving files from linux share on IIS 6.0

Tags: linux, iis, iis-6, hosting, fileserver

dHi, I'm trying to setup my IIS server (6.0) to serve files from a linux share.
As I'm pretty unfamiliar with linux I ask the community for any input on this.

I've had problems even having IIS server serve content from another windows machine share, this could be a prolem with our domain.  The iis server is not on the domain.

As I want to move more towards open source and linux I think having a simple file server is a good way to start.

I took the linux distro chooser at http://www.zegeniestudios.net and it recommends OpenSuse/Mandriva/Ubuntu.
Any oppinions on that would be welcome aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Samba](http://www.samba.org/) to crate a Windows share on Linux.